# var a = (<div>Rome</div>) How does this syntax work in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I came across a weird syntax which actually seems to work, but I am not sure how.

```js
function Person(props) {
  return (
    <div className="person">
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <p>Your Age {props.age}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

var app = (
  <div>
    <Person name="Rank" age="42"/>
    <Person name="Frank" age="22"/>
  </div>
)

console.log(app)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

What I do not understand is the second syntax, var app = (..).

I know that content of app would be used by React Compiler to generate createElement kind of code at the end which can be understood by the browser. What I don't understand is the syntax of assigning to app variable which isn't even a valid javascript syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `app` is `element` written with JSX syntax and you are rendering it into the DOM. So, it is not Javascript as you thought but it is a valid React syntax, being JSX here.

We are rendering JSX into the DOM in React. Either directly using an `element` written with JSX like in your example or using a `component` **which returns** a JSX element or elements. Again, in your example if you use `Person` component instead of `app` it will return a JSX and you will render it into the DOM.

Just go and examine the introduction to JSX on [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

Answer (score 0):

Babel will transpile your code before actually running it. In this case, babel will transform those JSX using a plugin like `babel-plugin-transform-jsx`.

You can try it online [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAFAKBjAPAEwJYBuAfBpvBDnBaVgPT7FoCUA3EA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=).

So, actually when you write this code:

```
const a = (
  <div>
    asdasd
  </div>
);
```

Babel will transpile it into:

```
var a = React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  "asdasd"
);
```

You see, every JSX is actually just a call to `React.createElement` with some arguments passed to it. Because it will be insanely inefficient and frustrating to code React app while typing `React.createElement` over and over, the developer of React allow us to use JSX syntax instead. This helps developers to work better and faster, but requires the code to be transpiled before being run.